# How to send shipment email notification using rest api magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email, rest-api, shipment

How we can send email notification of shipment using rest api

> /V1/shipment/:id/emails

what parameters and what need to change in url need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have researched and found how we can do this.

**Details**

http://domain/rest/V1/shipment/10/emails   :  where 10 is the shipment id

**Method** : post

**parameters** : {}

When will hit then a mail will go of shipment to the respected customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the service /V1/order/{orderId}/ship with field `"notify": true`

customer will get an email notification!

[More Info On Swagger](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesShipOrderV1/salesShipOrderV1ExecutePost)